# Click custom UITableViewCell the label constraint missed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I made a custom tableViewCell in my tableView, the cell using auto layout and in my view controller I used

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 61.5;
```

to compute cell height, every thing is perfect but when I click it, the selection style will let it be wrong like the following picture.

[Correct layout like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYb9l.png)

[After selection had the wrong layout like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZZyz.png)

The different between these two picture is the constraints(gap) of title label and time label was missing.

When I change the selection style to ***UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone***, this bug doesn't happening.

Is their have some solution can fix this problem without disable the selection style? Or something setting missed when I using auto layout result to this problem?

Thanks for everyone!

Comment: what's the priority of the vertical spacing between time and the bottom of the cell ?

Comment: Bottom Space to: Super view Equals: 7, is any setting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

well what your doing is specify that you want a distance of 7 between the bottom and the label time I guess there is a vertical space between the title and the time label too , if after you change the height of the cell , the constraint stay and get into an undetermined state . What You can do is to change the priority of the constraint (the one you can accept to change ) you can see the priority by clicking on the constraint with the Utilities (the right side menus in Xcode)  , and give the constraint an inferior priority like 500 , you can also change the relation of the constraint , (change to equals to greater than or equals)

Comment: I want to know what happened when I click the tableView cell, why this action will change the layout of my cell?

Comment: do you change something in didSelectRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: No, it just go to the other view controller to edit this record.

Comment: I test it again and again, I did't set the name label width and when I click the cell, the label width will be changed.

Comment: If you simply reload the data what happen ? in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Not thing happen, but if I put reload table in view did appear method, when I go back this controller the layout will renew at first time I see it. But if I click again it will be change again.

Comment: Well after taking a second look at the picture , I see that the probleme can come  from : the constraint between the title and the top or the title and the time , try to set the constraint priority between the title an the time at 500 and see what happen

Comment: Got the same problem, nothing different. :(

Comment: I meant the inverse set the constraint between the top and the title at 500 and the one between title and time at 1000

Comment: I tried, nothing  different, maybe it just a bug when selection style redraw the view and the constraints be compute wrong?